# How to make links open on main Chromium window when opened on a different virtual desktop in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, browser, chromium, virtual-desktop

If the browser is open on desktop 1 and a different application on desktop 2 opens a link, it creates a fresh new window on desktop 2 instead of the one already open in desktop 1.

I want to make it so that it opens on the originally opened window all the time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible and will not change in the near future.

Here is the answer from the bug-report
[Issue 1061661: On a new desk, clicking on the Chrome icon always opens a new window instead of listing open windows](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1061661&q=virtual%20component%3AUI%3EShell%3EWindowManager%3EVirtualDesks&can=2)
from Mar 14, 2020:

> I can share a bit of background on the current behavior. We know that
> a lot of desk users split up their projects and tasks across desks and
> want windows on other desks to be out of their visibility. We wanted
> to make it easy for users to open Chrome on a new desk and **we
> interpret the user intention in this case to be to open Chrome on the
> current desk rather than switching desks and revisiting an existing
> window**.
>
> This is currently working as designed but we appreciate the input and
> will revisit this behavior if additional research and feedback
> indicates a mismatch with user expectations.

Your only option is to add more feedback on the Chromium forums,
but the final word is, quote: "This is currently working as designed".

Comment: Is there any workaround I can use?

Comment: You may move the browser window to the next virtual desktop with a shortcut, but it will not become part of the exiting window in that virtual desktop. I can only suggest to try another browser that is not Chromium-based.

Comment: @harrymc I can confirm that this works as expected in Firefox (the only major browser not to be Chromium based)